# How to implement custom soft constraints in OR-Tools Routing Solver?

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

I've been working with the OR-Tools routing solver in Python for a couple of months and I still not understand how to implement custom soft constraints or even if it's possible in the routing solver.

I know that the following methods add penalties to the cumulative values:

```
SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(self, index: int64, upper_bound: int64, coefficient: int64)
SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(self, index: int64, upper_bound: int64, coefficient: int64)
```

One of the constraint I'm not able to implement is the following:

- I want to penalize the distance/time consumed by empty vehicles. For instance, in a pickup and delivery scenario if the vehicle does a delivery and becomes empty, I want to penalize the distance traveled while empty until the vehicle reaches a pickup node (next node) or ends the route.

With the above methods I can only penalize with a fixed value when a bound is exceeded, but I would like to penalize the consumed distance or time to transit to the next node.

Meanwhile, is there any way to implement custom soft constraints with an explicit penalty value considering the state of the solution found (e.g., the next node and cumulative amount of the dimensions)?

Comment: I'd be curious to know as well, but tbh I don't think this can be easily done in or-tools. In my experience this is easier to achieve in other solvers.

Comment: @k88 Could you suggest other solvers? I will try the JSprit or Octaplanner.
If the route is deterministic for instance, in a taxi VRP, we know that before any pickup the car is driving in empty and we can create a cumulative dimension that cumuls only the distance to pickup nodes/end-nodes and then penalize that distance with soft upper bound. But in a mix-approach, I think it's not possible, unless we use dependent dimensions (that depends on the capacity dimension), but it's only supported in C++ and the performance is not that great.

Comment: I have good experience with Optaplanner and I know it extremely flexible. You can do this quite easily in Optaplanner using Drools. I think it is also possible with LocalSolver, but that one is commercial.